# No source location was provided

Tags: checkmarx

I am running checkmarx from the CLI plugin.
Here's my command:

```
    runCxConsole.cmd scan -v -ProjectName "THE PROJECT NAME" -CxServer MY SERVER -CxUser amr\test -CxPassword password –Locationtype folder –locationpath "C:\Users\test\Documents\source_code\" –ReportPDF "C:\Users\test\Documents\reports\report.pdf"
```

And on my folder source_code I have projects with source code. It is there. I have checked many times. This is the output I receive

[image]

What is the problem? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try this? 
runCxConsole.cmd Scan -Projectname "CxServer\SP\Company\Users\bs java" -CxServer http://xx.xx.xx.xx -cxuser user@cx -cxpassword pass -locationtype folder -locationpath "C:\Local_Projects\BS java Small1" -preset Default -v

and replace with your info...